# How can i pass setup args to pytest testmethod decorator/fixtures

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-decorators, pytest-fixtures

```
class TestXYZ:


    @pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
    def setup(self, before_function, after_function, test_details):
        self.cluster_details, self.account_details, self.application_details, self.testrail_details = test_details

    @my_decorator(('arg1','arg2'))
    def test_1495990_verify_sensor_device_status(self,print_arguments): 
        """
        Step 1 :: Precondition
        - Adding Device to workspace
        """
        print('test started')
```

In `@my_decorator` (it takes the args and performs some operation) how can I pass setup variables such as `self.cluster_details` and `self.account_details` instead of 'arg1' and 'arg2' ?

Comment: What's `my_decorator`?

Comment: Thats a simple decorator takes arguments and print them.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano any help here?

Comment: The inner function of your decorator should be able to access self.cluster_details and self.account_details